# How can i generate a page dynamically in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I'm building a site in Django but I'm kind of stuck with the following problem.

In my *home.html* I have a list which looks something like this:

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}


{% block content %}


<body>


<div class="itemlist">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="item1">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="item2">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="item3">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="item4">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

</body>



{% endblock %}
```

This list is updated dynamically, so there will be more and different `items`.

This is what I'm trying to do: for each of those items, when I open the item's link, a new page should be opened, containing data about the item, like this:
**site.com/item1**, or **site.com/item2**

The problem: I can't create a view and a template for each item since the list will grow. Creating a view, a template and a url for each is not a doable solution.

A possible approach: create a view that generates a standard page and append the link to that page, like this:

**site.com/items/`item-here`**, so for example **site.com/items/item15**

The problem is that I'm fairly new to Django, so I don't know how to apply this approach practically.

Can someone give me a hint on where I should go from here? Every advice is appreciated. I hope my problem was understandable.

Comment: But that is exactly how Django normally works. Have you done the tutorial? That shows how to do this with the example of poll questions, with a separate page for each question.

Comment: Hey @DanielRoseman! What tutorial do you mean? Yeah i know, it's a base task. I perfectly know how to generate a template in Django, i think what's difficult for me here is that, in this, case, i need to generate the template randomly. What i'm used to do is: add a section to my site, create the view and add the url. Doing it with a long list, and with each element of the list, was another different task for me

Comment: Try creating a function view like ```def render_items(request, item_id):``` - google **Django function views with input parameters**.

Comment: Looking into it, thanks!

Comment: You'll also find how the value `items` from function view is transferred to your actual template when it's rendered.

Comment: Hi there, You could use https://wagtail.io/ for it. It's a Django CMS! It's great and very neat and easy to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use FBVs. One view and one template required.

**Views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def render_items(request, item_name):
    item = get_object_or_404(YOUR_MODEL, YOUR_ITEM_FIELD_NAME=item_name)
    return render(request, 'YOUR_TEMPLATE.html', {'item': item })
```

**Add below line to urlpatterns**

```
    path('items/<str:item_name>/',views.render_items, name='item'),
```

**Detail Template**

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body>
    <div class="item-detail">
        <h1> Detail </h1>
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```